# How does $\mathrm{Spec}$ behave with (co)limits?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, category-theory

I have read several times that $\rm Spec:(CRing)^{op}\to Top$ is  functorial, but I have never seen anything about its behaviour with limits and colimits. In class we noticed that $\mathrm{Spec}(R_1\times R_2)\cong \mathrm{Spec}(R_1)\sqcup\mathrm{Spec}(R_2)$ set-theoretically, and since  the prime ideals  of $R_1\times R_2$ are of the form $\mathfrak p\times R_2,R_1\times\mathfrak q$, the topology is the one of the disjoint union.

In Pete Clark's Commutative Algebra, paragraph 4.3, it is shortly described how to recover the fiber of a map between spectra, and I think that he uses the following: given a ring homomorphism $A\to B$, let $k$ be the fraction field of $A/\mathfrak p$, for a prime ideal $\mathfrak p\subset A$; then the tensor product $k\otimes _A B$ is the pushout of $B\leftarrow A\to k$, and $\mathrm{Spec}(k\otimes _A B)$ is the pullback of $\mathrm {Spec}(B)\to \mathrm {Spec}(A)\leftarrow \{\mathfrak p\}$, which is exactly the fiber over $\mathfrak p$. However this is a special case (one ring is a field);  are  in general  the pushouts sent to pullbacks? Does $\rm Spec$ satisfy more general properties about limits and colimits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a functor $CRing^{op} \rightarrow LRS$, it preserves limits because it's right adjoint to the global sections functor. See [Lemma 26.6.4 of the Stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01I1). Therefore, colimits in $CRing$ (which are limits in $CRing^{op}$) are sent to limits.

However, it doesn't send limits to colimits, as the $Spec$ of an infinite product of rings is not the infinite disjoint union. $Spec(-)$ is always compact, but an infinite disjoint union is not compact.

As for $CRing^{op} \rightarrow Top$, the same argument above shows it doesn't send limits to colimits. It doesn't send colimits to limits either. The coproduct in $CRing$ is $A, B \rightarrow A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B$. Setting $A = \mathbb{Q}$ and $B = \mathbb{Z} / n  \mathbb{Z}$., we get $A \otimes_\mathbb{Z} B =0$, so its $Spec$ is the empty set. However, $Spec(A) \times Spec(B)$ (where the product is taken in $Top$) is not empty, since neither $Spec(\mathbb{Q})$ nor $Spec(\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z})$ are empty.

Comment: Thanks; do you confirm instead that, in the case of the fibered product, a pushout is sent to a pullback?

Comment: $CRing \rightarrow LRS$, yes. 

$CRing \rightarrow Top$: no, consider $\mathbb{A}^1_k \times_k \mathbb{A}^1_k  = \mathbb{A}^2_k$. But they don't have the same underlying sets. For example, $\mathbb{A}^2_k $ has extra generic points.

Comment: I expressed badly in my comment; I meant that the pushout of a diagram like $k\leftarrow R\to A$, with $k$ field, is sent to the pullback of the induced diagram in $\rm Top$.

Comment: Again, no. Consider $Spec(\mathbb{C}) \times_{Spec(\mathbb{R})} Spec(\mathbb{C})$. In $LRS$, this is 2 points, but in $Top$, this is one point. All rings involved are fields.

Comment: Sorry. Instead of the arbitrary field $k$, I should have placed $k(p)$, the field of fractions of $R/p$, for a prime ideal $p\subset R$. At this point we can say that $k(p)\times _R A$  is sent to the pullback of the induced diagram in $\rm Top$ right?